# Use lookup values to create new pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame containing stocks that looks like this:

```
    Name                Ticker        Currency
0   TOTAL SA            FP FP         EUR
1   APPLE INC           AAPL US       USD
2   ALPHABET INC-CL A   GOOGL US      USD
```

I have another containing prices:

```
             AAPL US   FP FP    GOOGL US
Date
2018-08-01   200.0000  55.0000  1235.0000     
2018-08-02   201.0000  56.0000  1236.0000
2018-08-03   202.0000  57.0000  1237.0000
```

and another containing FXs:

```
             EUR        USD
Date
2018-08-01   1.1300     1.3000  
2018-08-02   1.1400     1.3100
2018-08-03   1.1500     1.3200
```

I want to create a new DataFrame with the same columns as the price one containing FX rates.  I want to do that by using the currency column of the stocks DataFrame as a lookup and selecting the correct values from the FX DataFrame so I get something like this:

```
             AAPL US   FP FP    GOOGL US
Date
2018-08-01   1.3000    1.1300   1.3000    
2018-08-02   1.3100    1.1400   1.3100
2018-08-03   1.3200    1.1500   1.3200
```

I cannot seem to find the right function that allows me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you begin with 3 dataframes: `stocks`, `prices`, and `fx`. You can then use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a series mapping:-

```
# create mapping from ticker to currency
s = stocks.set_index('Ticker')['Currency']

# reindex fx with data from prices, then rename columns
res = fx.loc[prices.index, prices.columns.map(s)]\
        .set_axis(prices.columns, axis=1, inplace=False)

print(res)

            AAPL US  FP FP  GOOGL US
2018-08-01     1.30   1.13      1.30
2018-08-02     1.31   1.14      1.31
2018-08-03     1.32   1.15      1.32
```

Comment: This did the trick.  However as a side note, it is worth noting that I received the following warning when running this. 'FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative'.  I checked and all labels matched so not sure why this warning appeared. I marked this as the correct answer as it was considerably quicker than the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
final_df = df_prices.copy()
cols = final_df.columns

final_df.columns = final_df.columns.map(df_stocks[['Ticker', 'Currency']].set_index('Ticker').to_dict()['Currency'])

final_df.update(df_fx)
final_df.columns = cols
```

Outputs

```
>>> print(final_df)

           AAPL US  FP FP   GOOGL US
Date            
2018-08-01  1.30    1.13    1.30
2018-08-02  1.31    1.14    1.31
2018-08-03  1.32    1.15    1.32
```

Comment: This solution worked and the function seems to be for the specific reason, but was just slower than the alternative suggestion on my dataset  - 6s vs 55ms